# Could not find default endpoint element error in web application referencing own service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, configuration, endpoint, service-reference

I have created a WCF service using ASP.NET 4 and am trying to connect to it *inside my own web application project*, which gives me the "Could not find default endpoint element" error.

None of the answers to this similar question seem to help me, since they all seem to deal with an external project that references the service and is missing a configuration file.

The service works when its methods are used directly (ex: JS calls).

Any ideas? Please view my serviceModel section below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MapiWebService.CrmService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:64049/Service/CrmService.svc"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="MapiWebService.CrmService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:64049/Service/CrmService.svc/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here're the opening lines of my service class:

```
namespace MapiWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CrmService : PortalService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string Authenticate(string username, string password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<endpoint address="http://localhost:64049/Service/CrmService.svc/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>` to

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

And try `http://localhost:64049/Service/CrmService.svc/mex` for referencing your service.

Update:

Your contract should be your `[ServiceContract]` interface unless `CrmService` is your `ServiceContract`

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="MapiWebService.ICrmService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't fix the issue, however; I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that normally I wouldn't even have to specify the address of the service to reference it since I'm in the same project. I just open the Add Service Reference dialogue in VS > click on Discover > choose my service, and it should be ready for use.

Comment: Failed to notice it before, but is `MapiWebService.CrmService` your `ServiceContract`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? MapiWebService is the namespace I'm using for the CrmService service class.

Comment: Are you annotating `CrmService` class with `[ServiceContract]`, if not it is your service implementation which is also called `[ServiceBehaviour]` which is only implementing the actual service contract.

Comment: I have added the opening lines of my service class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code for both client application's service Model and WCF service Model.(In web config file)

For Client App web config..

```
      <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="UserSiteApp.AjxWcfService" >
    <endpoint contract="UserSiteApp.AjxWcfService" binding="webHttpBinding" address=""  behaviorConfiguration="UserSiteApp.MyServiceTypeBehaviors" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="04:10:00" openTimeout="04:10:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <!--<compressionMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="binaryMessageEncoding" />-->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="VInfotechEndPointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1500000000" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="UserSiteApp.MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>



</behaviors>

<client>
  <!--Intranet Service-->
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:50004/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="your contracts Interface address" behaviorConfiguration="VInfotechEndPointBehavior" name="WSHttpBinding_IIntranet">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>


    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>

</client>
```

For WCF Servic web config

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IntranetService" behaviorConfiguration="IntranetService.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IIntranet">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  <service name="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.MobileServicesController" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
    <endpoint address="RestService" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="VInfotech.Server.Intranet.IMobileServices" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
             sendTimeout="10:15:00"
             openTimeout="10:15:00"
             receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
             maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest" >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
    </binding>
    <!-- For Cyber Source bindings-->
    <binding name="ITransactionProcessor" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <!--Cyber Source bindings ends here-->
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="IntranetService.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ServBehave">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
    <behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ITransactionProcessor" contract="ITransactionProcessor" name="portXML"/>
</client>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: What do you mean by client and service models? I am trying to reference my service in its own .NET application project. Who is the client in this case, where should the app.config go?

Comment: So you mean your are creating only one application inside your solution. Generally in web application we are adding multiple solutions for our web application. In same scenario we are creating a separate wcf project in our web application for service.

Comment: Nilesh, can you explain to me why it matters how many applications will be using my service? Furthermore, I have tried referencing my service from an external application, and I'm getting the same exception. I really don't have any leads on this...